# connecting a SSH tunnel on reboot?

Tags: ssh, reboot, autostart, autossh

How can i reestablish a Tunnel if my localhost goes down?

i have 2 machines, Remotehost and localhost, on my localhost im running autossh to keep the tunnel alive in case of network problems.

```
autossh -M 20000 -L 3300:192.168.2.101:3306 -R 3000:192.168.1.3:3000 disp@192.168.2.100 -p 80
```

but what if i need to reboot the localhost? how do i auto reconnect the tunnel then?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Put the command to establish the tunnel in some script which is executed on boot. You could use /etc/rc.local, you could write your own init script in /etc/init or /etc/init.d, or more elegantly, you could write a script in /etc/network/if-up.d. The last option executes the script after the network interface comes up.

Comment: Calling it on /etc/network/if-up.d will not make it be called again and again every time interface get down and up again?

Answer (score 9):

Another simple option is to add `@reboot autossh ... &` to `/etc/cron.d/autossh`

Comment: This will look as: `@reboot autossh -f -nNT -R 3269:host-providing:3269 firewalled-host &`

Comment: no need to add "&" at the end, -f already place the command in background